# Excel raw date number representation incoherency

Tags: c#, excel, process, exceldatareader

[C# 9.0 and net7.0]

(* main request edit)
(Why can excel have the same date value representation as different dates? 43708 can be 31/08/19 and 01/09/23)

#### As stated by @user8728340's response, this happens because of a misalignment of bool literals representations. When scheffer represented it as "true" and the excel default (and what the library expected) was "1".

*(A github issue and pool request have been created to solve the problem)*

More information about the outcome of this observation can be found in the problems github issue *("DateTime incoherent value")*

I have a `.xlsx` file from a `HttpClient` request and read these bytes as a stream. I'm trying to use `ExcelDataReader` in the stream; I detected that datetime values are not correct. The table has only one column of date and all dates start in 2021.

All the datetimes read with the `IExcelDataReader` are specifically `31/08/2019` - this cannot be because of the above statement.

When I tested it in my personal computer the dates returned right what I realized is in order to transfer this file to my computer I had to save it using Excel.

The stream from the request has ~2079 bytes while the (saved by Excel) file has ~5569 so I compared the byte structure in both files in notepad++ and tested a lot to ensure that the original version in fact never returns the dates right (every other data is correct) but the modified one is perfectly fine. I tested this behavior in 3 machines and the results are the same. So, here is the deal

I'm already using the `ExcelDataReader` library so I would like not to use another to solve the same problem.

The origin file from the request ends with "Implementation by Anton Scheffer" literary written to the file

**Clarification**

[image: this is the origin file from the web request]

While the Excel saved version eds with a more understandable manner

[image: The modified by Excel version]

Looking into the `.xlsx` file structure as a `.zip` in windows, we can access the entry: `xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml`, storing the table's data from the file. In the 14º column, the date one, the value written to the file is `43708` this value can be interpreted by excel in two ways,
as 31/08/19 or 01/09/23. I don't know what defines that.

Comment: typically we see these types of things when using excel having either different runtime localizations on the machine or actual file formats. specific for datetimes such settings as the Environment settings and using the excel capabilities imlicitly using those
You could be lucky it's one of those.

https://serverfault.com/questions/948175/how-to-adjust-the-format-of-win-system-environmental-variables-date

Comment: @T.Nielsen, I tried modifying the region configuration but it just inverted the numbers position. Unfortunately remains the same date value

Comment: You can look inside an XLSX file pretty easily (as a programmer).  They are ZIP files, mostly containing a folder structure and XML.  If you rename a .XLSX file to .ZIP, and open it with a zip file tool, you can look around inside your file.  Don't expect much enlightenment by looking at the binary stream.  The OpenXML SDK Productivity Tool can let you inspect the structure of an OpenXML file (which is what a .XLSX is) and tell you what's wrong with it.  Microsoft has it hiding on GitHub these days (the last time I went hunting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Excel library that created this file - PL/SQL "as_xlsx" by Anton Schleffer - saves files with a non-standard value for the "date1904" workbook property.  Excel itself sets the `date1904` property to `1`, but in files produced by "as_xlsx" it is `true`.  ExcelDataReader does not support this particular deviation and proceeds to return wrong dates off by 4 years.

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing seems dependent on the date system set in your Excel application for the workbook.

Using the 1904 date system, `43708` will convert to `1-Sep-2023`
Using the 1900 date system, `43708` will convert to `31-Aug-2019`

The setting is under `File=>Options=>Advanced=>When Calculating this Workbook`

[image]

Excel stores dates as serial numbers starting at either `1/1/1900` or `1/1/1904` depending on the date system selected.

Most windows installs default to the 1900 date system. Mac installs used to default to the 1904 date system. You should be aware that the 1900 date system has a deliberate error (supposedly to be compatible with a Lotus 123 accidental error) wherein 1900 is considered a leap year.

See [Differences between the 1900 and the 1904 date system in Excel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/1900-and-1904-date-system) for a more detailed explanation.

Depending on your requirements, you may need to change the date system in the workbook, or use the `1462` constant you have derived.

Comment: Thank you for the souce and carefull explanation from the excel perspective. Even tho in the application (c#) i couldn't use the excel interface to configurate this whenever was needed to process the report, the knowledge gave by you remains totally usefull

Answer (score 0):

I detected that the date always shifted 1462 days in the past constantly. I know it doens't solve the root of the problem but its a solution to our business for now. Adding the missing days to the readed value fixes the problem.

Thanks to @Flydog57 for explaining that xlsx files are structured as zip files so i could access the file internal content and read the xml raw data. The values written to the xml's content at the target column is 43708 which is, the number representation of the date 31/08/2019 literally. In the excel saved version of the file the same value 43708 is represented as 01/09/2023, the reason for that remains unknown.

comparasion:
raw file:
[image: at the raw request content]
excel saved file:
[image: at the excel's modified version]

Comment: I'll mantain the question open because this date raw value representation incoherence is interesting and i really would like to known why that happens

Comment: i'm thinking about removing the c# context and tags from here, since the question focus shifted and not much code is envolved

Comment: Inside the xlsx there should be some XML like, `<workbookPr date1904="true" defaultThemeVersion="124226"/>` - this tells Excel/ExcelDataReader how to interpret the numeric date values. The bug is that date1904 flag doesn't pick up in ExcelDataReader - altho it should!